# javascript function not returning expected geometric sequence

Tags: javascript, html

Haven't been able to find my problem why this function is not returning the expected values when the button is clicked. Tried just about everything but no luck. Need a bit of help where I might look to solve this. Looking at the plus side was able to figure out previous 3 sequences with no issues. Here's what I have and it runs fine. The problem is  ar^n where a=4 and r=3. The output should display:

```
When n=1; 4x3=12
When n=2; 12x3=36
When n=3; 36x3=108...etc
```

```js
    function sequence4() {
 var i;
 var num = 0;
 var result = 0;
 
  for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   var a = 4;
   var r = 3;
   num++;
   result = (a * r) * (num - 1);
   document.getElementById("seq4").innerHTML+="When n= " + num + "; " + num + "x 3 = " + result + "<br>";
  }
}

sequence4()
```

```html
<div id="seq4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer, change result line to

```
result = a * Math.pow(r, num - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting, used that formula in slightly different configuration and the results were closer to expectation. This hit it right and now the entire sequencing program works.

Answer (score 0):

i think you've got the formula for the series wrong:

```
n=1 ->  4*3 = 12 = 4*3     = 4*3^n
n=2 -> 12*3 = 36 = 4*3*3   = 4*3^n
n=2 -> 36*3 = 36 = 4*3*3*3 = 4*3^n
```

So I think you wanted:

```
result = a * (r ^ num);
```

not:

```
result = (a * r) * (num - 1);
```